# Creating a windows directory on a vsphere_virtual_machine using terraform

Tags: windows, terraform, vsphere

Using terraform I'm trying to create vsphere_virtual_machine resource. As part of it, I'm trying to find out how to mount virtual disks to a specific folder on a created virtual machine.  For example :

**Terraform**

```
disk {
  label = "disk0"
  size = "100"
}

disk { 
  label = "disk1"
  size = "50"
}
```

How to mount disk0 to volume path D:\mysql\conf and disk1 to volume path D:\mysql\databases on a windows vm created using terraform vsphere_virtual_machine ? Could someone please share your insights here . Thanks in Advance !!

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing in the vsphere_virtual_machine provider that will handle internal operations like that against the Virtual Machine, and I'm not aware of any other provider which can do that either.

Couple workarounds:

- check out the [remote-exec provisioner](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/remote-exec.html), this will let you run some PowerShell or other CLI commands to perform the task you need.
- If you're doing this on a regular basis, check out Packer. It can be used to build out a virtual machine, OS and all. You could establish the disk configuration there, then use Terraform to deploy it.
- Lastly, look into configuration management utilities. Ansible, PowerShell DSC, Puppet, Chef, etc. These tools will let you make modifications to the VM after they've been deployed.